# RabbitMQ works in localhost, but throws BrokerUnreachableException in LAN - (.NET Windows environment.)

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I'm trying to work with RabbitMQ in a project.

I've installed RabbitMQ Server `rabbitmq-server-3.4.4.exe` on Win8 (64bit) PC, which has the IP 192.168.100.6.

I have added a user using `rabbitmqctl add_user username password` in RabbitMQ command prompt.

Tried to receive the message as follows-

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "skp";
factory.Password = "111";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Protocol = Protocols.DefaultProtocol;
factory.HostName = "localhost";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
        try
        {
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

                    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

                    Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                             "To exit press CTRL+C");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                        var body = ea.Body;
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

When the hostname="localhost", it works fine.

But if I try to connect from other PC on LAN and hostname="192.168.100.6", it throws a `BrokerUnreachableException` - "None of the specified endpoints were reachable"

What I missed here?

UPDATE:
Firewall on 192.168.100.6 (RabbitMQ Server) is turned off.

Comment: Have you properly set up the RabbitMQ exchange at that endpoint?

Comment: I followed the RabbitMQ official documentation. Is there any additional config required? I'm not sure. Please help.

Comment: are you using the guest user?

Comment: I tried guest user as well with this line {loopback_users, []} in cofig file.

Comment: Do you have firewall turned on? Maybe it blocks connections and you have to temporary disable it to check that and then add RabbitMQ to it exceptions.

Comment: @zac178miami Firewall is turned off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is about the UserName & Password.
Follow [this instruction](https://programmershandbook.wordpress.com/2015/03/22/rabbitmq-setup/) to install and run your RabbitMQ Server.

Then browse http://localhost:15672/. This will open the RabbitMQ management login page. Add a user i.e. "abc" with password. Add all the tags shown below i.e. "administrator,management, policymaker".

Now use the following code to your client-

```
       var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "192.168.100.6", Password = "123", UserName = "abc" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

                var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                         "To exit press CTRL+C");
                while (true)
                {
                    var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Setting username and password on connection factory instance solved the BrokerUnreachableException issue for me, cheers!

Comment: Thanks, the password and username did it for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the port number I thought the default is 5672 but my rabbitmq instance (using docker) was running on 5673. To find the port number rabbitmq is currently using (in docker) click on the container -> Inspect > Ports.

If a wrong port no is used - error message "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException" with inner exception "ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be ..."

If the wrong username or password is used - error message "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException" with inner exception "AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED"